# how to paste the Image in MessageComposer

Tags: objective-c, uipasteboard

I had copied the image as data to UIPasteboard, i need this image to be automatically pasted to Message Compose without the user interaction. how to do it ?

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard setData:imageData forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

Comment: You should indicate under what conditions the image needs to be pasted - as it is your question is too general.

Comment: Image should be pasted when the Message composer initialised.

Comment: what you could do is attach the file to the compose view

Comment: the image data is not attaching to the body of the MFMessageComposeViewController.